# Import classes in subpackages into main namespace with Python package

Tags: python, package

I'm trying to re-organise my code-base into a proper Python package (with subpackages) ready for uploading to PyPI. I have the following directories (for testing):

```
Py6S/
    __init__.py
    test.py
    Params/
          __init__.py
          AeroModel.py
```

AeroModel.py contains:

```
class AeroModel:
    NO_AEROSOL=0
    CONTINENTAL=1
    MARITIME=2
    URBAN=3
    USER=4
    DESERT=5
    BIOMASS_BURNING=6
    STRATOSPHERIC=7
```

The Py6S **init**.py contains:

```
__all__ = ["Params"]
```

The Params **init**.py contains:

```
__all__ = ["AtmosModel", "AeroModel", "AtmosCorr"]
```

However, when I do `from Py6S import *` I get Params available to reference, but not AtmosModel or AeroModel.

I want to be able to type `from Py6S import *` and get all of AeroModel, AtmosModel, AtmosCorr etc available to use without having to put any module names in front of them.

Comment: I would suggest you not to give the same names to modules and their classes as it creates slight confusion. Use small letter for modules names (PEP 8). So, in your case, it should be `aeromodel.py` module containing class `AeroModel`

Comment: @Guanidene - Thanks. Does that help give some solution to the comment I've put on the answer below? I'd like to be able to import the class AeroModel easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Py6S's `__init__.py` has `from Params import *`:
you'd need to do:

```
import Params
__all__ = ["Params"]
from Params import *
__all__ += Params.__all__
```

to add those to Py6S's `__all__`

Comment: Do you really need `from Params import *` to access `Params.__all__`?

Comment: No but you need it if you what the names that `Params` lists in its `__all__` in the current namespace.

Comment: @Dan - That works well to get the modules of AeroModel, AtmosModel etc imported - thanks. However, once I've run `from Py6S import *` I have to reference the AeroModel class (the only class in the AeroModel module) as `AeroModel.AeroModel`. Is there a way to make it so that the *class* is imported as opposed to just the module?

Comment: @robintw - you need to modify your `__init__.py` in the folder `Params` to this - 
`from aeromodel import Aeromodel;`
`__all__ = ["atmosmodel", "aeromodel", "atmoscorr", "Aeromodel"]`

Comment: @robintw -In my previous comment I have written the module names in small letters (and class names in CapitalWords) just to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ Dan D. - why are you importing `Params`? I think there is no need for it.

Comment: @Guanidene if you only do `from Params import *`, the name `Params` is not bound to the module, thus the need.

Comment: @ Dan D. - what you say seems to be right, but I don't know how I am able to import Py6S and also modules aeromodel, etc. without adding `import Params` in Py6S's `__init__.py`